# crypttab and VeraCrypt

Tags: cryptsetup, veracrypt

I dual boot Fedora and Windows Vista and want them to share a partition so that I can work on the same files in both Linux and Windows, and I need everything to be encrypted.

I encrypted the shared drive with [VeraCrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Home.html) since TrueCrypt is out of date. Windows can mount the volume at login with ease.

I tried to do the same in Linux but with no luck since I can't figure out how to use `crypttab` with the `veracrypt` option, or even if it has one.
`cryptsetup` works fine since it's just necessary to add the `--veracrypt` option, but `crypttab` does not seem to have that.

```
cryptsetup --veracrypt open --type tcrypt /dev/sdX veracrypt-volume
```

How do I mount a VeraCrypt volume with `crypttab`? Is it possible yet?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem!  Turns out systemd was lacking such an option, so I have implemented it myself.  It is included in systemd 232 or later.  (You also need cryptsetup 1.67 or newer for the actual cryptography support, but it sounds like you have that since the manual mount works.)

The new crypttab option is `tcrypt-veracrypt`; it implies `tcrypt` so you don't need to specify that separately.  For example:

```
#Volume name  Device path     Crypto key file     Mounting options  
 data         /dev/sda7       /etc/volume.passwd  noauto,tcrypt-veracrypt
```

Of course, you need to put your crypto key (with **no newline**) in `/etc/volume.passwd`.  Also note that if you're trying to decrypt a **system partition** you need to indicate that using the `tcrypt-system` option, because it won't detect the different format without it.  Here's an example.  I'm also demonstrating the use of the `UUID=` volume specifier here.

```
 data         UUID=your-uuid  /etc/volume.passwd  tcrypt-veracrypt,tcrypt-system
```

See [the pull request I made](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/4501/) for more info about `tcrypt-veracrypt`.

Comment: The mapped device will then be available as `/dev/mapper/data` which you can then include in your `/etc/fstab` or `mkdir /media/tcdata && mount /dev/mapper/data /media/tcdata`

Comment: I was unable to get this working as described on Debian 10 Buster.  For some reason the password file wasn't being handled correctly by `cryptdisks_start` (confirmed it had no new line at the end).  It eventually worked with the options `tcrypt,veracrypt,keyscript=/bin/cat,noearly`.  Not sure why passing the passphrase through `/bin/cat` would make a difference, nor why `tcryrpt,veracrypt` worked over `tcrypt-veracrypt`.