# How to mount VeraCrypt or TrueCrypt volumes with the boot password

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, boot, cryptsetup, veracrypt

For Windows, VeraCrypt implements a feature called "system favorite volumes". 
It allows mounting additional discs
with the password entered at boot to unlock the system partition.

Specs: I am running Pop OS! 22.04,
which should be equivalent for this question to Ubuntu 22.04. 
My system partition is encrypted with LUKS. 
I want to mount three volumes: one with VeraCrypt encryption
and two with the original TrueCrypt encryption.

I have found several articles to tackle this problem;
however, none of them worked:

- [Auto-mounting a VeraCrypt volume under Ubuntu / Debian Linux – Computer Correct](https://www.computercorrect.com/2018/operating-systems/linux/ubuntu/auto-mounting-a-veracrypt-volume-under-ubuntu-debian-linux/)
- [VeraCrypt - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/VeraCrypt)
- [crypttab and VeraCrypt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203048/crypttab-and-veracrypt)

I am completely lost and cannot even test my trials.

Answer (score 1):

You can unlock truecrypt volumes and veracrypt too with your system boot (luks) password with at least Debian and Ubuntu. A Veracrypt volume with a PIM needs at least v254 of systemd for the `veracrypt-pim=<number>` option within cryptab. See here https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/crypttab.html

For Debian 12 systemd is v252 so install v254 systemd from backports to use `veracrypt-pim=<number>` within cryptab. Then as well as having all your volumes using the same password, add `initramfs,keyscript=decrypt_keyctl` options at the end of the lines. The `initramfs` pulls the decrypting of the volume to the start of the boot with the system drive and `keyscript=deycrypt_keyctl` caches the password so you only have to enter it once.

For crypttab along with your system drive unlock line something like this. Note that the `initramfs` is not needed for the line unlocking the system volume:

```
# System volume
sda3_crypt UUID=6b3229c1-6f6a-480f-8524-212f6bd2e4dc none luks,discard,keyscript=decrypt_keyctl
# Truecrypt volume
sdb_true /dev/disk/by-partuuid/7d185b93-01 none tcrypt,discard,initramfs,keyscript=decrypt_keyctl
# Veracrypt volume.
sdc_vera /dev/disk/by-partuuid/2c175e93-01 none tcrypt-veracrypt,discard,initramfs,keyscript=decrypt_keyctl
```

Veracrypt volume needing a PIM you need systemd v254 or later:

```
sdc_vera /dev/disk/by-partuuid/2c175e93-01 none tcrypt-veracrypt,veracrypt-pim=20,discard,initramfs,keyscript=decrypt_keyctl
```

After making your crypttab (and fstab to mount the drives) entries and checking it very thoroughly! run `# update-initramfs -u -v` to update grub.

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR:

- edit the `/etc/crypttab` to feature the devices; like

  ```
  # existing lines from the system setup
  cryptdata UUID=ca....5c none luks
  cryptswap UUID=9a...91 /dev/urandom swap,plain,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64,size=512
  # added lines
  givenname1 /dev/sdb2 none tcrypt,tcrypt-veracrypt #add the tcrypt-veracrypt option for a device encryted with veracrypt
  givenname2 /dev/sdc2 none tcrypt
  givenname3 /dev/sdd1 none tcrypt
  ```
- add the following lines to the `/etc/fstab` like

  ```
  /dev/mapper/givenname1 /mnt/mymountpoint1 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
  /dev/mapper/givenname2 /mnt/mymountpoint2 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
  /dev/mapper/givenname3 /mnt/mymountpoint3 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail 0 0
  ```

#### How to test

After editing the `crypttab` file you can call `cryptdisks_start` with e.g.
`sudo cryptdisks_start givenname1`. If this works it might still not work at startup, but you are on the right way.

To test if it will work at startup perform the folloing steps

1. this will reread the crypttab file

   ```shell
   sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   ```
2. this will start the service, this might yield false positive results if you have successfully called cryptdisks_start previously

   ```shell
   sudo systemctl start systemd-cryptsetup@givenname1.service
   ```
3. to rule out false positive results restart the service

   ```shell
   sudo systemctl stop systemd-cryptsetup@givenname1.service
   sudo systemctl start systemd-cryptsetup@givenname1.service
   ```
4. check if the a link has appeared in `/dev/mappers`

   ```shellsession
   $ ls  /dev/mapper/

   control  cryptdata  cryptswap  data-root  givenname1
   ```

#### Attention Ubuntu users

Ubuntu implements the cryptsetup scripts differently than most other distributions. As a result some options in the crypttab are missing for ubuntu and similar distributions.

Compare the man page for the exact changes.

- https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lunar/en/man5/crypttab.5.html
- https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crypttab.5.html

For me this meant that I could not use a keyfile in conjunction with the password since the option `tcrypt-keyfile` missing.

To test which options are available to you call `man crypttab`

#### Remarks

This solution works quite well for me. Mounting the discs is also much faster that with the veracrypt GUI.

For a typical dual boot scenario, the mounted drive might have the NTFS filesystem. Here the mount options should be different.

I have tried these additional parameters in the `/etc/fstab`:

```
uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=027,fmask=137
```